# Composer: How to override a requirement globally for composer.json?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

## TL;DR:

My Project requires library A, A requires B1.
B1 is broken but there is a fork B2. 
I want to achieve that composer will install B2 instead of B1 even if A requires B1 and not B2.

How to do that?

## More in detail:

In a symfony project we require the following library:

```
"require": {
   "emanueleminotto/twig-cache-bundle": "1.0.2",
}
```

This library [requires itself](https://github.com/EmanueleMinotto/TwigCacheBundle/blob/master/composer.json#L18) another library that is currently broken:

```
"require": {
    "asm89/twig-cache-extension": "^1.3"
},
```

For the broken library exists already a [pull request](https://github.com/asm89/twig-cache-extension/pull/46) for over 4 month but the maintainer refuses to merge it.

My question is, if it would be possible to overwrite the dependencies also for sub-dependencies, that always the patched fork would be used instead of the original one?

For the asm89/twig-cache-extension exists the following fork with fixes: https://github.com/blackandred/twig-cache-extension

I tried to add this fork to my composer.json and registered the fork explicitly under "repositories":

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/blackandred/twig-cache-extension"
    }
],
```

and added the dependency also in my composer-json with a changed version to "dev-master":

```
"require": {
    "asm89/twig-cache-extension": "dev-master",
    "emanueleminotto/twig-cache-bundle": "1.0.2",
}
```

But since the *emanueleminotto/twig-cache-bundle* still requires the original library, composer ignores the fork and installs the original.

Anything i can do here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the docs have a [good example](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md#require-inline-alias) for this scenario.

Basically you need to define an alias in your composer.json as following:

```
"require": {
    "asm89/twig-cache-extension": "dev-master  as 1.3",
    "emanueleminotto/twig-cache-bundle": "1.0.2",
}
```

*Added by the questioner:*

One step was still missing: `"composer update asm89/twig-cache-extension"`

Comment: Important note: library like https://github.com/blackandred/twig-cache-extension must have the same `name` attribute i composer.json like original, e.g. `asm89/twig-cache-extension` instead of `blackandred/twig-cache-extension`

Answer (score 3):

Add the [`replace`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#replace) section into `composer.json` of your fork:

```
{
    "replace": { 
        "asm89/twig-cache-extension": "self.version" 
    } 
}
```